# How to save the selected MKAnnotation?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, mkmapview, mkannotation, callouts

I have an app that has a mapview, and it shows 20 pins (from an Array) on the map. When the user clicks on it, it can show a bubble with a right accessory button. 
Here come my problem: How do I know which pin was pressed?
I heard something about the mapView:didSelectAnnotationView method, but I don't really understand how do you get the pin/callout index, so that I can get the information of the object at the same index of my Array? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When that method gets called -- because your viewController class has adopted `MKMapViewDelegate`, you can call `-indexOfObject` on the array and get the index of that pin (annotation). This is with the assumption that your array holds objects of the kind of annotation class.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
        // Annotation is your custom class that holds information about the annotation
        if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
            Annotation *annot = view.annotation;
            NSInteger index = [self.arrayOfAnnotations indexOfObject:annot];
        }
    }
```

If you need more explanation, we need to know how you are adding those pins, i.e. implementation of `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`.

Comment: is it supposed to be `didDeselectAnnotationView`? or the didselectedAnnotationView?

Comment: @RobRoyRyan There are actually both, but I actually meant didSelectAnnotationView. When you first select an annotation, didSelectAnnotationView gets called. When an annotation is selected, and you tap anywhere else on the map, didDeselectAnnotationView gets called. When an annotation is selected, and you select another one, first didDeselectAnnotationView and then didSelectAnnotationView gets called.

Comment: @Canopus i am getting same index for every annotation when i click on it and these are not single digit ?? means i am getting index for e.g. 2147483647 like this ?? I followed above logic ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution to Canopus'.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) 
    {
        NSInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];
        NSLog(@"%d",index);
    }
```

Note: I was manually adding annotations to the map and then viewing their respective indexes.  They don't get indexed in the order they are added to the mapView.  i.e., just because you added a annotation as the fourth annotation it may have an index of 1 or 3 or whatever.  Someone may have a explanation for that but it has eluded me till now.  Hope this helps.